# How to capture mouse events at console application in Xamarin.Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

How to capture kmouse events at console application in Xamarin.Mac, NSEvent is disable.

Comment: Check https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html

Comment: If you create an override for MouseUp, and place a breakpoint in it, is it hitting the breakpoint? public override void MouseUp(NSEvent theEvent)
{
    base.MouseUp(theEvent);
}

Comment: Thank for your answer, but the NSEvent must run in ui progress. My application don't run in ui progress, I want use CGEvent to capture mouse events but i don't how to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knowed how to use CGEvent capture Mouse Event, as follows ：

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NSApplication.Init();

        var call = new CGEvent.CGEventTapCallback(Callback);

        var data = new IntPtr();

        var eventTap = CGEvent.CreateTap(CGEventTapLocation.HID, CGEventTapPlacement.TailAppend, CGEventTapOptions.Default, CGEventMask.MouseMoved, call, data);

        var cfMachPort = new CFMachPort(eventTap.Handle);

        CFRunLoopSource runLoopSource = cfMachPort.CreateRunLoopSource();

        CFRunLoop.Main.AddSource(runLoopSource, CFRunLoop.ModeCommon);

        CGEvent.TapEnable(eventTap);

        CFRunLoop.Main.Run();

    }

    public static IntPtr Callback(IntPtr eventTap, CGEventType cGEventType, IntPtr eventRef, IntPtr usrInfo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("鼠标移动了");
        return eventTap;
    }
```